# Solspace Freeform Pro - Add value to field using segment

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is it possible to use a segment as a Freeform input field value? Essentially, something like this...

```
{freeform:field:name attr:placeholder="Name" attr:value="{segment_3}"}
```

I know I could just do a hidden input, but I want to suggest the value and allow the user to modify it if it's wrong.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{freeform:field:first_name default_value="{segment_2}"}
```

https://solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#freeform_field_field_name

Dwam. There be your answer. Tested on `EE 2.10.1` and `FreeForm 4.2.2`.